# Elementary proof of the equidistribution theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, elementary-proofs, irrational-numbers, equidistribution

I'm looking for references to (as many as possible) elementary proofs of the Weyl's equidistribution theorem, i.e., the statement that the sequence $\alpha, 2\alpha, 3\alpha, \ldots \mod 1$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval. With "elementary" I mean that it does not make use of complex analysis in particular the [Weyl's criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeylsCriterion.html).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Weyl's criterion doesn't use complex analysis, just basic properties of complex numbers, and it can be stated without complex numbers at all (for example using real trigonometric functions). 

Comment: What is your definition of equidistributed?

Comment: Pablo: Since Carlo refers to Weyl's criterion under the label "complex analysis", probably he means "complex numbers".  Personally I think restating Weyl's criterion using trig functions in place of e^{ix} would make the situation look overly complicated. 

Comment: Presumably, any basis of $L^2$ would work (orthogonal polynomials of some sort), but I don't really see the point, since Weyl's proof is half a page.


Comment: Have you checked the Kuipers-Niederreiter book to see if there's a non-Weyl proof there?

Answer (score 30):

There is a really easy proof that just uses the Pigeonhole principle. Let $\alpha$ be irrational.

**Lemma:** For any $\delta >0$, there is an $n>0$ such that $(n \alpha) \in (- \delta, \delta) \setminus \{ 0  \}$.

**Proof:** Choose $N$ large enough that $1/N < \delta$. Divide $[0,1]$ up into $N$ segments of length $1/N$. By pigeonhole, there are $j$ and $k$ such that $(j \alpha)$ and $(k \alpha)$ land in the same segment. So $((j-k) \alpha) \in (-\delta, \delta)$. Since $\alpha$ is irrational, $((j-k) \alpha) \neq 0$. $\square$

Now, fix $0 \leq p < q \leq 1$ and $\epsilon>0$. Our goal is to show that
$$\begin{multline*} q-p-\epsilon \leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \inf \frac{\#\{ k \leq N : (k \alpha) \in (p,q) \}}{N} \\
\leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \sup \frac{\#\{ k \leq N : (k \alpha) \in (p,q) \}}{N} \leq q-p+\epsilon. \end{multline*}$$

Choose $\delta >0$ such that
$$\frac{(q-p)/\rho -1}{1/\rho+1} \geq q-p-\epsilon \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{(q-p)/\rho +1}{1/\rho-1} \leq q-p+\epsilon$$
for all $\rho$ with $|\rho| < \delta$.

Choose $n$ such that $(n \alpha) \in (-\delta, \delta) \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Write $\rho = (n \alpha)$.
Break up the set of values $(k \alpha)$ into arithmetic progressions based on $k$ modulo $n$. So each segment is of the form $(\beta + j \rho)$. It is enough to prove that the lim inf and lim sup contributed by each progression lie between $q-p-\epsilon $ and $q-p+\epsilon$, as the total contribution is a weighted average from the contributions from the progressions.

Break each progression up into segments according to $\lfloor \beta + j \rho \rfloor$. The initial segment and final segment each contain at most $1/ |\rho|$ terms. The segments in the middle contain between $1/\rho - 1$ and $1/\rho+1$ terms of which between $(q-p)/\rho -1$ and $(q-p)/\rho+1$ are between $p$ and $q$. Since $((q-p)/\rho-1)/(1/\rho+1)$ and $((q-p)/\rho+1)/(1/\rho-1)$ were chosen to lie in $(q-p-\epsilon, q-p+\epsilon)$, the average of all of these terms lies in the required interval. And the terms from the initial segments can only drag the average off by at most $(2/|\rho|)/(N/n)$, which goes to $0$. QED.

Answer (score 8):

Hardy and Wright give a proof based on continued fractions in [Section 23.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=P6uTBqOa3T4C&pg=PA520) of "An introduction to the theory of numbers" (reference valid at least in the 4th edition).

Interestingly, their [endnotes to Chapter 23](https://books.google.com/books?id=P6uTBqOa3T4C&pg=PA522) claim that the "equidistribution" form of the theorem is not due to Kronecker (the statement they call "Kronecker's theorem" is the density of $\{n\alpha\}$; they give a number of elementary proofs of that weaker result), but "independently to Bohl, Sierpinski and Weyl".

Comment: Probably Harold Bohr, not "Bohl"...

Comment: @paulgarrett It is actually P. Bohl: https://eudml.org/doc/149304

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, aha! Thanks for that clarification!

Answer (score 6):

An elementary proof was given by Alberto Zorzi in

*[An Elementary Proof for the Equidistribution Theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-014-9505-x)*
*The Mathematical Intelligencer
September 2015, Volume 37, Issue 3, pp 1–2*

Unfortunately the article is behind a paywall. The proof makes use of the following elementary criterium for equidistribution. As usual, $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part of a real number.

LEMMA 1. A sequence $(x_n)$ is equidistributed in $[0,1)$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( {1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^N \{x_n\} - {1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^N \{x_n+a\}\right) = 0.
$$
for any real number a.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this qualifies, but there is a short proof using Fourier Analysis.  No hardcore stuff, just Fejér's Theorem.  See [Chapter 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=OcZ5iKsGrmoC&pg=PA11) of Körner's *Fourier Analysis* book (there are 110  chapters in the book, so this really is one of the first things that is covered).

Comment: This would basically be Weyl's proof, I think - the key idea there is to smooth the characteristic function of the interval [a,b] on which one wishes to count points n\alpha. The Fejer kernel (or de la Vallee Poussin kernel) is one way to do that. (I'd have to admit that I haven't bothered actually going to look at the book before making this comment.) 

Comment: I have to admit that I hadn't bothered actually going to look at Weyl's proof before posting this answer.  

Answer (score 4):

Here is an elementary proof for the equidistribution of orbits of irrational rotations. Let $\alpha$ be any irrational number and fix $0\le a<b\le 1$. We need to show that

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:equidistribution}
\frac{\# \left\{0\le j < n\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\}}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}b-a.
\end{equation}

The idea is to choose a rational number $p/q$ close enough to $\alpha$ with a large enough denominator, then take $n$ large enough and use the facts that the orbits of a rotation by $p/q$ are evenly spaced within the unit interval, with a distance of $1/q$ between orbit points, and that orbits of the rotation by $\alpha$ stay close to orbits of the same point under rotations by $p/q$ along pieces of orbits of size smaller than $q$. In this respect the current proof is motivated by and similar to the proof by Hardy and Wright mentioned on this page.

We will need the following standard and easy-to-prove lemma:

**Lemma:**
Assume $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers satisfying
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq:best}
\left|\alpha-p/q\right| < \frac{1}{q^2}.
\end{equation}
Then for every $0\le i < q$ there exists a unique $0 \le j < q$ such that $\{j\alpha\}\in \left[\frac{i}{q},\frac{i+1}{q}\right)$.

**Proof:**
Without loss of generality assume that $\alpha > \frac{p}{q}$. Then $0 < j\alpha - j\frac{p}{q} < \frac{1}{q}$ for every $0\leq j<q$. Writing $jp = s_j q + r_j$ with $0\leq r_j<q$ we see that the integer part of $j\alpha$ is $s_j$ which implies $\frac{r_j}{q} < \{j\alpha\} < \frac{r_j+1}{q}$. Since $p$ and $q$ are coprime the map $j\mapsto r_j$ is a bijection on $\{0,\ldots,q-1\}$ so we are done.

Getting back to our sheeps, fix any $\varepsilon>0$. By Dirichlet's theorem there are arbitrarily large rational approximations to $\alpha$ that satisfy \eqref{eq:best}. Choose $p$ and $q$ coprime that satisfy \eqref{eq:best} with $q$ large enough ( such that $\frac{1}{q}<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ ), and choose $N$ to be large enough ( such that $\frac{q}{N}<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ ).

Then, for any $n\ge N$, write $n = sq+r$ with $0\le r < q$. The following estimate holds:
\begin{align*}
\# \left\{0\le j < n\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\} & \ge
\sum_{t=1}^{s} \# \left\{(t-1)q\le j < tq\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\} \\
& \ge s\left(q(b-a) - 2\right) \\
& =  n\left(b-a\right) - 2s - r(b-a).
\end{align*}

In the second inequality the number of subintervals from a partition of the unit interval into $q$ subintervals of length $1/q$ that intersect $[a,b]$ bounds the number of orbit points in $[a,b]$. The error in this count is at most two, the reason being that in any partition of the interval into subintervals there are at most two subintervals that intersect $[a,b]$ but are not contained in it. Since $\frac{s}{n} \leq \frac{1}{q} < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ and $\frac{r}{n} \leq \frac{q}{n} < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$, this proves that

$$
\frac{\# \left\{0\le j < n\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\}}{n} \ge b-a - \varepsilon.
$$

The other inequality is proved similarly:
\begin{align*}
\# \left\{0\le j < n\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\} & \le
\sum_{t=1}^{s+1} \# \left\{(t-1)q\le j < tq\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\right\} \\
& \le  (s+1)\left(q(b-a) + 2\right) \\
& =  n\left(b-a\right) + 2(s+1) + (q - r)(b-a),
\end{align*}
so,
$$
\frac{\# \{0\le j < n\,:\,\{j\alpha\} \in[a,b]\}}{n} \le b-a + \varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, this proves \eqref{eq:equidistribution}.